# Passing multiple arguments to a tableadapter using SQL statement

Tags: c#, sql, tableadapter

I'm attempting to pass multiple arguments to a fill Tableadapter method in Visual Studio and i'm getting a "The method or operation is not implemented" error when i run it in the program.  I have a vague understanding of C# but still learning.  VS is not finding any errors in the code and the SQL Query works just fine when i test it in DataSet designer.  The coding makes sense to me and i feel like it should be working but i'm obviously missing something, i just can't for the life of me figure out what it is.

This is the start of a timesheet program.  What's supposed to be happening is when the user clicks the search button, it runs the query and displays the results.  The query takes the employee name chosen from a dropdown box and displays all the entries for that employee that falls within the date range chosen from the two datetimepickers.  Below is the SQL statement, which as stated works fine when testing... then the code for the button click which is where i must be missing something.  Can anyone figure out why i might be getting that error?

```
SELECT Customer, Department, Brand, Model, TotalTime, AMPM, InvoiceNumber, Date, Day, TechName, EntryID, Remarks
FROM Entries WHERE TechName = @TechName AND Date BETWEEN @Date1 AND @Date2


        private void searchButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            if ((techNameComboBox.Text.Length > 0)
            && (dateDateTimePicker.Text.Length > 0)
            && (dateDateTimePicker1.Text.Length > 0))

            try
            {
                this.entriesTableAdapter.FillByDateRange(
                    this.timeSheetEntriesDataSet.Entries, (techNameComboBox.Text, dateDateTimePicker.Text, dateDateTimePicker1.Text));
            }

            catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                }
          }
```

Comment: Which dbms are you using? `DATE` is an ANSI SQL-2016 reserved word, and also by some dbms products (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_reserved_words)

Comment: Does Server have more than one database?  What is the default database in teh connection string?  If you have more than one database in the server you could either add the default database in the connection string or add to the query "Use Database_Name; Select.........".

Comment: I am using the newest version of SQL Sever Express with Management Studio 18.

Comment: This is the connection string visual studio created when i connected to the database 

        <add name="HBMTimeSheet.Properties.Settings.TimeSheetEntriesConnectionString"
            connectionString="Data Source=homeserver2019\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=TimeSheetEntries;User ID=local

Answer (score 0):

You've probably solved this by now, but if your query was

```
SELECT Customer, Department, Brand, Model, TotalTime, AMPM, InvoiceNumber, Date, Day, TechName, EntryID, Remarks
FROM Entries 
WHERE TechName = @TechName AND Date BETWEEN @Date1 AND @Date2
```

In the tableadapter, then the method signature would be

```
FillBy(table, tech name, date1, date2)
```

But you appear to be calling it by trying to pass a valuetuple

```
FillByDateRange(this.timeSheetEntriesDataSet.Entries, (techNameComboBox.Text, dateDateTimePicker.Text, dateDateTimePicker1.Text))
```

First, remove the parentheses around the arguments.  Second, if the date column in the db truly is a date then the arguments for date1 and 2 will be c# date time types, not strings, so you should pass Value from the datetimepicker

```
FillByDateRange(timeSheetEntriesDataSet.Entries, techNameComboBox.Text, dateDateTimePicker.Value, dateDateTimePicker1.Value)
```